# how to setup the delegate for UIPageViewController inside Container view that is embeded in a ViewController

Tags: swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `MainViewController`, that has a container view inside it that embeds a `UIPageViewController`. `MainViewController` conforms the protocols `UIPageViewControllerDelegate, UIPageViewControllerDataSource`
and I want the embedded `UIPageViewController` to be delegated by the `MainViewController`.
Is that even possible?

Basically I am trying to have a similar attitude to having a collection view inside a view controller as an outlet from storyboard, and then to setup the delegates for it (`collectionView.delegate = self`, assuming self delegates it)
So this attitude with a `UIPageViewController`. 
The obstacle I encounter is that there is no `PageView` as opposode to `PageViewController` (comparing to collection views, I have `CollectionView` as opposed to `CollectionViewController`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps you could use to produce this:

You can get a reference to your UIPageViewController by overriding `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` in MainViewController. This function is triggered when your embedded controller is made a child.

Given you gave your segue a name (let's use **pageSegue** for this example), you are able to do something like this in MainViewController:

```
func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "pageSegue", let controller = segue.destination as? UIPageViewController {
        controller.delegate = self
        controller.dataSource = self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a reference to your page view controller to your main view controller in the following way:

```
var walkthroughPageViewController: WalkthroughPageVC? {
        return self.children.first as? WalkthroughPageVC
}
```

from here, you can just set `walkthroughPageViewController.delegate = self`

This method only works of course if you have one embedded view controller.

If you have more than one, Thomas' method above is better for grabbing the specific view controller you want.